# Make record JSON-convertible as `string` in SwaggerUI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger-ui, .net-8.0

I have a `record` that implements string conversion:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ExamplePropJsonConverter))]
public record ExampleProp
{
    private string? Value { get; init; }
    
    public static implicit operator string(ExampleProp value) => value.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    public static implicit operator ExampleProp(string value) => new ExampleProp() { Value = value };
    public override string ToString() => (string)this;
}

public class ExamplePropJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ExampleProp>
{
    public override ExampleProp Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.GetString() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ExampleProp value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
}
```

I want it to make JSON representation in API as ordinary string easy way.

And I have controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("/ep-test")]
public IResult TestEP([FromBody] ExampleProp ep) => Results.Json(ep);

[HttpPost("/string-test")]
public IResult TestString([FromBody] string s) => Results.Json(s);

[HttpPost("/string-as-ep-test")]
public IResult TestStringAsEP([FromBody] string s) => Results.Json((ExampleProp)s);
```

It works OK except SwaggerUI:

In SwaggerUI I see:

- /ep-test 
   Example value: `{}` 
   Schema: `ExampleProp:{}`

And I would like to see scheme like url has, or at least string:

- /ep-test 
   Example value: `"string"` 
   Schema: `ExampleProp: string`
- /ep-test 
   Example value: `"examplePropFormat"` 
   Schema: `ExampleProp: string($exampleProp)`

I expect that there may be some magic attribute I'm missing like `[JsonConvertAs(typeof(string))]` that may both throw away explicit converter implementation and tell Swagger to interpret type as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add these lines to your `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
{
    o.MapType<ExampleProp>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" });
});
```

More info: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#override-schema-for-specific-types

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to do same via attributes?

Comment: @filimonic I checked the source of the package just now but couldn't find any other way, sorry